# In a pandas dataframe (python 3) column, I need to standardize all instances of (for example) "PO BOX", or "P O Box" or "POBOX", etc. to "BOX"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 30 or so synonyms that could be found in an address to indicate a PO Box. I would like to be able to scan an address and if one of these synonyms are in the address, change it to simply BOX.

First of all, I'm new to Python.  I am a seasoned SAS programmer, trying to learn Python.  I've tried using a dictionary with the .map() function (thinking this would work like a SAS format), but with no luck.  Then I tried something like:
df['address'] = df['address'].replace({'PO BOX': 'BOX', 'P BOX': 'BOX', 'POSTBOX': 'BOX', 'P O BOX': 'BOX', 'POB': 'BOX'}, inplace=True)

The input looks like this: (sorry for the bad formatting)

- id         address

  0       13943    PO BOX 1234

  1      14738   510 BLUE BELL RD

  5     27455   5887 CORNERS AVENUE

  6     27457   200 NEW HAVEN DR SUITE 10

  9   1595554   POBOX 908

  10  1595971   101 W 7TH STREET

  14  1597234   P O BOX 616

And I want it to look like:

```
  id         address
```

0     13943   BOX 1234

1     14738   510 BLUE BELL RD

5     27455   5887 CORNERS AVENUE

6     27457   200 NEW HAVEN DR SUITE 10

9   1595554   BOX 908

10  1595971   101 W 7TH STREET

14  1597234   BOX 616

But what I'm getting is this:

```
   id    address
```

0     13943   None

1     14738   None

5     27455   None

6     27457   None

9   1595554   None

10  1595971   None

14  1597234   None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to use a pd.Series but it's the same as one dataframe columns.

```
rep = {'PO BOX': 'BOX', 'P BOX': 'BOX', 'POSTBOX': 'BOX', 'P O BOX': 'BOX', 'POBOX':'BOX', 'POB': 'BOX'}


address = [
"13943 PO BOX 1234",
"14738 510 BLUE BELL RD",
"27455 5887 CORNERS AVENUE",
"27457 200 NEW HAVEN DR SUITE 10",
"1595554 POBOX 908",
"1595971 101 W 7TH STREET",
"1597234 P O BOX 616"
]
```

Create pandas series.

```
s = pd.Series(address, name='Addy')
```

Use replace and regex equals True.

```
s.replace(rep, regex=True)

0                     13943 BOX 1234
1             14738 510 BLUE BELL RD
2          27455 5887 CORNERS AVENUE
3    27457 200 NEW HAVEN DR SUITE 10
4                    1595554 BOX 908
5           1595971 101 W 7TH STREET
6                    1597234 BOX 616
Name: Addy, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think my lack of experience on this site may have hindered my ability to display the data correctly.  The data is actually more like this:

Comment: the first column is the INDEX, the second (the 5-7 long digit) is the "id" and the last part is the address.  (I can't figure out how to show it correctly formatted) :(  So, I need to just replace the address column.

Comment: Thanks run-out!  I ended up pulling the address out of the dataframe (a series), using the replace and then overlaying the address in the dataframe with the modified address